# How can I get the relative and absolute cursor position?

Tags: java, position, swt, mouse-cursor

How can I get the current **position of the Cursor** with SWT?

I need:

1. The **absolute** position (only relative to the current `Display`)
2. The position **relative** to the currently active `Control`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This gets the Cursor position **relative to the current Display**:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
[...]
Point cursorLocation = Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation();
```

To get the position **relative to the focused Control** you have to translate it:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
[...]
Point cursorLocation = Display.getCurrent().getCursorLocation();
Point relativeCursorLocation = Display.getCurrent().getFocusControl().toControl(cursorLocation);
```