# How to get the mouse position from nattable cell for rcptt testing?

Tags: java, eclipse, nattable

As i started working on RCPTT and for testing context menu on NatTable it needs mouse x & y coordinates, but i want to test it with cell position instead x & y positions of mouse.

So i taught of writing custom implementation for RCPTT for mose-press ecl-command with cell positions.

To do this i need to get the mouse coordinates after selecting the cell.

Is there a way to find the mouse position after selecting /editing the cell with EditCellCommand/SelectCellCommand?

So i will pass the cell positions for custom mouse-press ecl-commant instead mouse pointers and then trig the cell command and get the mouse cordinates and then use this coordinates for mouse press ecl command.

Answer (score 0):

That is an SWT related question and not NatTable specific. I think the answer is already given in this topic: [How can I get the relative and absolute cursor position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356516/how-can-i-get-the-relative-and-absolute-cursor-position)

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to get the x and y positions from the cell bound.

```
ILayerCell cell = nattable.getLayer().getCellByPosition(this.COL_ONE, this.ROW_TWO);
Rectangle bounds = cell.getBounds();
int x = bounds.x;
int y = bounds.y;
```